# Como uso restricciones de caracteres en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero restringir un input a un caracter, no a un numero.

Esta es la parte de mi código que no funciona:

```
a=input("ingrese genero \n f: femenino \n m: masculino") <----

while (a!= f or a!=m): <----
    a=input("ingrese un genero valido") <----
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el `or` por un  `and` y las letras f y m ponlas dentro de Comillas, así: `while(a!='f' and a!='m'):`

Comment: te amo, muchas gracias

Comment: Debes de revisar como son los comentarios y agradecimientos en esta página, la ética, etc. De nada

Answer (score 0):

Puesto a que f y m no son variables, y las evaluas en tu `while`, estas deberán colocarse entre '' para que sean interpretadas como carácteres de tipo `string`

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
print("ingrese género \n f: femenino \n m: masculino")
a=input()
while (a!= 'f' and a!='m'):
    print("ingrese un genero valido")
    a=input()
```